How to configure buildSrc in Android project to generate libs from toml file
Im investigating using buildSrc in my current android project
i have created a buildSrc folder and specified Config constants that work fine in my apps gradle kts files.
object Config {

    object App {
        const val nameHeader = "APPLICATION_NAME"
        const val name = "Android My App"
        const val packageName = "org.research.development"
    }

    const val minSdk = 21
    const val targetSdk =  34

    val javaVersion = org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

i am now expecting i can generate the contents of the libs folder in my buildSrc module with the following changes, using my existing libs.versions.toml
buildSrc/build.gradle.kts
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinVersion

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

kotlin {
    compilerOptions {
        jvmTarget.set(JvmTarget.JVM_17)
        languageVersion.set(KotlinVersion.KOTLIN_2_0)
    }
}

buildSrc/settings.gradle.kts
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    versionCatalogs {
        create("libs") {
            from(files("../gradle/libs.versions.toml"))
        }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "buildSrc"

when i sync, clean and build though the libs folder stays empty
is it my expectations that need to change?
or am i missing a "trick"?

is our buildSrc folder is at the root level of your project? (not inside an app module)

also, try running ./gradlew --status and see for something that looks like Build script model : buildSrc/src/main/groovy/... (or /gradlew dependencies to see whether gradle actually sees the dependencies in the toml file)
